# Displaying BasicCard in Dialogflow response

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to display a BasicCard in dialogflow's fulfillment, but I always get this error message `MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set.`. The responseMetaData says `code 10` and `Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response`.

This is my code:

```
agent.add(`Check this out`);
agent.add(new BasicCard({
  title: 'Card Title',
  text: 'Description',
  image: {
    url: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
    accessibilityText: 'Google Logo',
  },
  buttons: new Button({
    title: 'Button Title',
    url: 'https://www.google.com',
  }),
}));
```

I'm using Cloud Functions for Firebase and

`"actions-on-google": "2.0.0-alpha.4",
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.3"`

and

```
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {BasicCard, Button} = require('actions-on-google');

const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
```

It works perfectly fine when I use new Card() instead of new BasicCard().

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have you tried

```
let conv=agent.conv();
conv.ask(new BasicCard({//Your code here
 });
```

Comment: It was 3 months ago, so I don't exactly remember what fixed this problem for me. If I recall correctly, it was updating "dialogflow-fulfillment" to 0.4.1, as there were some errors in the beta version I previously used. Though I also ended up using 'conv.ask()'. Either way, thanks for your suggestion.